# Need a way to properly check Az modules installed before running Install-Module

Tags: azure, powershell

My project requires installing Azure modules using these PowerShell commands during automatic deployment.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Install-Module -Name Az.ServiceBus -Scope CurrentUser
```

The problem is the first command usually takes an extra 10 to 15 minutes for every deployment on our TeamCity. I need to shorten it. One option that I have tried is to remove *-Force*. It seems working, reducing the deployment time to 10 minutes shorter.

However, when I checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-5.1, I saw it is stated that *-Force* key is designed to override any possible versioning conflict message. I am not sure if removing it will cause any problem in the future.

Another option that I have also tried is to wrap both commands using the following ifs

```
if(-not(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Az.* | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "Az.ServiceBus"}))
{
  Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Force
}

if(-not(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Az.ServiceBus))
{
  Install-Module -Name Az.ServiceBus -Scope CurrentUser
}
```

There is a problem with the 1st if bloc. Az has many modules in it. So I'm not sure

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Az.* | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "Az.ServiceBus"}
```

will provide desired results.

What if somehow by the time of deployment, for example only Az.Accounts module existing on the deployment server, while the others were not properly installed, it could still mark as ***Az*** existing and won't install other modules in it.

Could someone please give me advice on how should I properly check Az modules existing in a system?

Answer (score 0):

> Need a way to properly check Az modules installed before running Install-Module:

I've tried from my end by running `Get-InstalledModule` to check before Install-Module.

```
$ASBmodule = Get-InstalledModule -Name Az.serviceBus
if ($ASBmodule -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "Module exists" $ASBmodule} else {
    Write-Host "Module does not exist"
    Install-Module -Name Az.serviceBus
}
```

To check the installed PowerShell modules in the system, define the required modules in the variable (object) and check using the above `if loop` code, which also shows the version of that module if installed and if not, installs the module.

It will not install module every time if the condition is true.

[image]

***Update:***

```
$arrayvar = Get-InstalledModule -Name Az.*        
foreach ($array in $arrayvar){
if ($arrayvar -contains $array){
        write-host module exist}
    else{
        write-host module not exist
        Install-Module -Name $array}
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. The above approach can only work with a package that has only 1 module, like Az.ServiceBus. The problem is there are many modules inside Az package. How do I know which module has already been installed? Also there is no guarantee the list will stay as is. Microsoft could add more modules into the Az package in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, in that case we can store all the installed modules in an object and run foreach loop to check each and every module with the whole array and if it does not present in the list, we can give `Install-Module` command as described above. If that works for you, I can provide you the script relevantly.

Comment: I updated in the above answer. Please check. @Anthony